# System of equations solver pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, math, scipy

I have this Data Frame as example:

```
       Col1         Col2     ...    Col5       Price
 0     Wood         Wood            Plastic     50
 1     Iron         Wood            Wood        70
                            ...
3000   Iron         Iron            Wood        110
```

I would like to know if it's possible to build a linear solver N equation for N unknowns (in this example to find the Price of Wood, Iron, Plastic etc..)

Many thanks !

Comment: Columns in the table representing wood to be considered differently or not.

Comment: Take a look [Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html#numpy.linalg.solve)

Comment: It's the same values for all columns, Wood, iron, X1, X2... all the same. The idea is to find the price for them, The column Price is the Sum of the values for 1 row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The frame can be converted into a linear program, where each row in the frame is a constraint and each material is a variable. Then we can use [numpy solver](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) to solve the program ([Rajan Chahan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4465743/rajan-chahan) mentioned in the question comments).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from numpy.linalg import solve

# Create a simple frame, with two materials - Wood & Iron.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['Iron', 'Wood'], 'Col2': ['Wood', 'Wood'], 'Price': [3,2]})

# Extract the materials and map each material to a unique integer
# For example, "Iron"=0 and "Wood"=1
materials = pd.Series(np.unique(df.as_matrix()[:, :-1])).astype('category')

# Create a the coefficients matrix where each row is a constraint
# For example "Iron + Wood" translates into "1*x0 + 1*x1"
# And "Wood + Wood" translates into "0*x0 + 2*x1"
A = np.zeros((len(df), len(materials)))

# Iterate over all constrains and materials and fill the coefficients
for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in range(1, df.shape[1]):
        A[i, materials.cat.categories.get_loc(df.get_value(i, 'Col{}'.format(j)))] += 1

# Solve the program and the solution is an array.
# Each entry in the array correspond to a material price.
solution = solve(A, df['Price'])  # [ 2. 1.]

# Convert to a mapping per-material
material_prices = pd.Series(solution, index=materials.cat.categories)
# Iron    2.0
# Wood    1.0
# dtype: float64
```

In case the number of materials is different from the number of constrains, you can compute [least-squares solution](http://%20least-squares%20solution). Replace the line `solution = solve(A, df['Price'])` from the code above with:

```
from numpy.linalg import solve, lstsq
solution = lstsq(A, df['Price'])[0]
```

Comment: I'm getting LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square, do you have any idea ? When trying to passe solve()

Comment: Could it be that the actual frame is not N equations for N unknowns?

Comment: I have 54 different values for materials and I have about 4000 rows. I can pass 54 rows but I wish to keep them cuz its better

Comment: That's a little different case. Assuming a solution that satisfies all constraints exists, then `lstsq` will provide a solution. I've added the modification to the answer.

Comment: 1 Word: Genius !